Showing a triangle related equation
Let ABC be a triangle such that $AB\lt BC$ and $AC\lt BC$. Show that there exist 2 real roots of the equation: $$x^{2}-(AB+AC+BC)x+AB^{2}+AC^{2}=0$$. I figured that in order to show that, I'd have to show that the discriminant of the equation is positive, but when I simplified it, I got the expression $BC^{2}+2AB×AC+2AB×BC+2AC×BC-3AB^{2}-3AC^{2}$, which I couldn't prove that it's positive, so any help is much appreciated.

$f(0) >0$ and $f(a)<0$ is easily proved.

To simplify notation I will call the sides $a,b,c$ with $a<c$ and $b<c$.  The polynomial is
$$f(x)=x^2-(a+b+c)x+a^2+b^2\ .$$
We have
$$f(c)=a^2+b^2-(a+b)c=(a+b)(a+b-c)-2ab\ .$$
Now by symmetry, we may assume $a\le b$; so
$$0<a+b\le 2b\ ,\quad a+b-c<a\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(c)<2ba-2ab=0\ .$$
Thus $f(x)$ is a quadratic opening upwards which is negative for some value of $x$, and it therefore has two real zeros.
As far as I can see it is not actually important that $a,b,c$ form a triangle; the only thing that matters is that $a,b$ are both less than $c$.

It's customary to call $a$, $b$ and $c$ the lengths of the sides opposite to the angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ respectively, so your notation baffled me for a second and I wouldn't be surprised that others have the same problem.

Begin with using a standard and more sensible notation: $a=BC$, $b=CA$, $c=AB$.
Working with the sides of a triangle is often difficult because they must satisfy the relations $a+b>c$, $b+c>a$ and $c+a>b$, so a common trick to deal with that is to define $x = s-a$, $y=s-b$, $z=s-c$ where $s=\tfrac{a+b+c}{2}$. Solving for $a$, $b$ and $c$ gives $a=y+z$, $b=z+x$, $c=x+y$ and now the restriction on $x$, $y$ and $z$ is much more manageable: $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$.
Making the substitution in your problem: we have $c<a$ and $b<a$ which translate to $x<z$ and $x<y$. The discriminant of the polynomial $$f(x)=x^2-(a+b+c)x+c^2+b^2$$
is $(a+b+c)^2-4(c^2+b^2)$ which, after the substitution and simplification becomes $4(2yz-x^2)$ and this is obviously greater than $0$ since $y>x>0$ and $z>x>0$.

Using the standard notation of triangle side lengths being the lower-case letters of their corresponding opposite side upper-case letter angles, let
$$a = \lvert BC \rvert, \; b = \lvert AC \rvert, \; c = \lvert AB \rvert \;\;\to\;\; b \lt a, \; c \lt a$$
Due to symmetry, we can WLOG assume $b \ge c$. From your expression, call it $d$, using the lower-case letters and grouping the terms appropriately gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
d & = BC^{2}+2AB×AC+2AB×BC+2AC×BC-3AB^{2}-3AC^{2}\\
& = {\color{blue}{a^{2}}} + {\color{green}{2cb}} + {\color{green}{2ca}} + {\color{blue}{2ba}} - {\color{green}{3c^{2}}} - {\color{blue}{3b^{2}}} \\
& = ({\color{blue}{a^{2}}} + {\color{blue}{2ba}} - {\color{blue}{3b^{2}}}) + ({\color{green}{2cb}} + {\color{green}{2ca}} - {\color{green}{3c^{2}}})
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since $a \gt b$, we have $a^2 \gt b^2$ and $2ab \gt 2b^2$, so the first grouping has $a^2 + 2ba - 3b^3 \gt 0$. Similarly, with the assumed $b \ge c$, then $2cb \ge 2c^2$ and $2ca \gt 2c^2$, so the second grouping has $2cb + 2ca - 3c^2 \gt c^2$. Putting these together, we get the discriminant $d \gt 0$, i.e., the quadratic has $2$ real roots.
Note that, as indicated in David's answer, this only uses that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive real values, with $a$ being the largest, so it isn't limited to just triangle side lengths, which also requires $a \le b + c$ to satisfy the triangle inequality.
